# Playframework Restful servicestack with MV*

Tags: rest, design-patterns, architecture, playframework, playframework-2.0

We Love Play!!

Have used for small projects and pleased with the performance and productivity.

Need few suggestions or comments for the architecture for our new venture which is going to be on play-framework.

> Our new venture is to use REST Service stack built in
>   play-framework(Java) with any front end MV*. Moreover a SOFEA model.

Would like to see how secure we can make our application coz the app has some sensitive data in few endpoints.

**Question**:

- Does the design has any flaws
- What is the best way to secure our REST service stack
- Is it advisable to decouple my front-end app and back-end services
- Which front-end framework is best for this scenario.

Thanks

***Kindly suggest appropriate stack site if the question is Non-constructive rather just downvoting ;)***

**Edit**:  Anyone care to suggest / anwser? Added bounty.

Comment: 1. impossible to tell
2. there is not one best way, but oauth+https is one good way
3. depends on your requirements
4. there are many different front ends would work good

Comment: Ohh thanks. .will definitely tell you once I figure out. For sure best way.

Answer (score 0):

With any REST-based application, a main security risk is that you have no control over the client.  All data and REST requests being sent to the server must be fully checked for authorization.  That is: check that the user allowed to view this data and perform the action being requested?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @johanandren about the first one. It is impossible to say without in depth analysis of the design and the code.

Maybe you should have a look at the [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) framework for REST architectures. It is nice and it has very good [add ons](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Security/) for security.
There is also a very good [tutorial](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world) about it.

I am not sure what you mean by the last question. But if it is about how to return the data. Usually json is a good solution.

Good luck with our play project.